# Possible to synchronise AnimationDrawables in Android?

Tags: android, animation, synchronization

I need to synchronise two AnimationDrawables (using frame animations setup in xml). The developer article on AnimationDrawable speaks of no such thing, so I would like to know if it's even possible, and if not, how I could get the same effect using a different object perhaps? The two drawable objects are the same size and have the same number of frames, with the same duration between each frame.

Comment: I would like it to be at the exact same time. Issuing them in quick succession in code occasionally results in 2~4 frame lag which I can't afford to have unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up merging the animations together manually then played that one animation instead. It appears that it isn't possible since there is inevitable delay at some point (thread switching, etc).

For anyone else wishing to do this, I advise you take the slow way and redraw the animations you wish to combine and then play the one animation.

Comment: How you merged two animations? I have two, one simple rounded rectangle shape, black, orange, black orange. second is triangle shape xml (rotated rectangle in special way) blinking black orange too.